# Flutter: Mockito http client unit test exception

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, mockito, flutter-layout

I am trying to learn mockito http client test. So this is my test:

```
test(
  'should throw SocketException',
  () async {
    when(mockHttpCLient.get(any, headers: anyNamed('headers')))
        .thenThrow(SocketException);

    expect(
        () => foursquareRepositoryImpl.getVenuesDetails(venueId),
        throwsA(allOf(
            isArgumentError, predicate((e) => e is FetchDataException))));
  },
);
```

As you can see i want to throw `SocketException` when http get method is called:

This implemented method:

```
  @override
  Future<VenuesDetails> getVenuesDetails(String venueId) async {
    try {
      var response = await client.get(
          'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/$venueId?client_id={{client_id}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}&v={{v}}',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
    } 
    return null;
  }
```

But when i run my test i got this error:

```
Expected: throws (<Instance of 'ArgumentError'> and satisfies function)
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<VenuesDetails>>
   Which: threw FetchDataException:<Error During Communication: No Internet connection>
          stack package:foursquare_app/repository/foursquare_repository.dart 60:7  FoursquareRepositoryImpl.getVenuesDetails
                test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 157:23        main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                package:test_api                                                   expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 234:3                  expect
                test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 156:9         main.<fn>.<fn>
                ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
                package:test_api                                                   expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 234:3                  expect
                test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 156:9         main.<fn>.<fn>
                dart:async                                                         _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start
                test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 138:7         main.<fn>.<fn>

package:test_api                                            expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 234:3           expect
test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 156:9  main.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async                                                  _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start
test/repository/foursquare_repository_impl_test.dart 138:7  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Just change code bellow, will work fine.

```
...

expect(foursquareRepositoryImpl.getVenuesDetails(venueId),
        throwsA(isA<FetchDataException>()));

...
```

or

```
...

try{
     await foursquareRepositoryImpl.getVenuesDetails(venueId);
} catch (e) {
     expect(e, isA<FetchDataException>());
}

...
```